# I've reviewed the same post twice

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits, triage

I made [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8777654) in Triage, and then [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8777788) concerning the same post. I thought it was a test, so I reviewed it the second time too, but it was not a test.

How is it possible? Maybe it went back to the triage for some reason? Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at the review-items you provided, both times there were three for "Looks Ok" interspersed with two for "Should Be Improved".

Thus, it went into triage the first time probably due to the system selecting it, and the second time because someone outside triage flagged it as VLQ.

Now, should you be allowed to triage it a second time?
I don't think so, but whether it's common enough to explicitly disallow, and whether it's really a bug, I doubt that.

Comment: Yup - it went in and out of triage, got a VLQ a few minutes after which put it back into triage again...

Comment: Thank you, but now I have a question, also addressed to @JonClements, about the review I have done: Was it a good choice to give it a **Looks Ok**? I have passed all the review audits that were done to me but I want to know if I'm doing a good job **;)**

Comment: "I have a links to" already has a spelling error, so I would at least click should be improved.

Comment: I hope it is not a general consensus to hit "should be improved" when there is only a minor spelling error that does not in any way cast doubt on the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: @Gimby it does not look like a good question and I don't know much about that tag, so I would probably skip it, but it does not look like a "Looks OK" candidate to me.

Comment: @LisaMM: Pushing it into the H&I-queue for a minor typo is the wrong thing, remember that it's "should be improved", not "could be improved", and the goal is not a jewel of pristine beauty, but just an answerable question without too many defects. Now is it a good question? I don't think so, merely above the threshold. Also, I would be astounded if it isn't a common duplicate.

Comment: I'll remember that. I'm new to the review queues, so I'm still picking up the finesses (but I skip always when in doubt).

Comment: That button should totally say "must be improved" ffs