# Plan for reviewing same post on different review queues

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage, first-post-review

I've reviewed some posts for the *Triage* review and then later for *First posts*. It was allowed to me to examine a post which I've already reviewed at *Triage* at *First posts* again. This is a very strange behaviour, imho.

There is already a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285378/reviewing-the-same-question-in-first-posts-and-triage) for that. But it was asked 3 years and 7 months ago with only a comment

> *First Posts will eventually be replaced by Triage, per [the comments here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280850/how-to-review-a-first-post-question-that-clearly-belongs-on-another-stack-exchan/280852#280852)*.

Nothing happened so far.

There is a second [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299227/ive-reviewed-the-same-post-twice) where the user reviewed the same post twice in the same review process. This leads me to my question:

Shouldn't it be better for a post to be viewed only once by a user?

Comment: As each queue expects you to review a post in a specific context I don't think it is a major issue that you get the same posts multiple times.

Comment: @LucaKiebel Thank you for trying to improve this question by editing it. But this wasn't really an improvement. So sorry for the rollback. [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252504/2648551) and [this](http://grammarist.com/spelling/behavior-behaviour/) might be interesting for you.

Answer (score 1):

Each review queue has slightly different expectations, so generally it's fine for the same reviewer to examine the same post from different perspectives. The two queues with the most similar behavior, First Posts and Late Answers, still allow this, although it may be best for reviewers to skip one of the instances in order to get more eyes on the post.

Triage and First Posts, though, are sufficiently different that there's no real reason to worry. Triage requires multiple reviewers anyway, can't edit (or, usually, vote) directly, and is more focused on a simple judgement of a post than the thoroughness of First Posts.

Comment: I tend to agree. But as a reviewer you have to be disciplined to avoid being influenced by a previous decision from a different perspective. While on the one hand you should always be focused, this is also a source of mistakes that could easily be avoided by not showing already reviewed posts at all (reviewed by same user, of course).